# How to add sitemap of my mern website to Google search console

Tags: mern, sitemap

Hi I have a mern website running on vps now I want to add sitemap to Google search console I used a website and created a XML sitemap of my website and I am confused now what and where should I put it. I am a beginner and I am bit confused because everyone is just telling about how to do it on WordPress.